# stop jquery from replacing text

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do I get jquery to stop replacing text from an ajax request.

```
var nameid = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
$('#loadbox').load('mysqlquery.php?id='+nameid);

nameid++;

});
});// DONT DELETE
```

It pulls the info I want just when I make another call it replaces the previous word.

Comment: Replace **where**? In the `#loadbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.load()` .. use [`jQuery.get()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for the AJAX part and [`.append()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add them to the element you want (*while preserving the existing info*)

(*also you can indent you code to avoid comment like `// DONT DELETE`*)

```
var nameid = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.get('mysqlquery.php?id='+nameid, function(data){
            $('#loadbox').append(data);
        });
        nameid++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you just want to load once?

```
var nameid = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loaded = false;
    $('button').click(function () {
        if (!loaded) {
            $('#loadbox').load('mysqlquery.php?id=' + nameid, function () {
                loaded = true;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

***Update:***
If you want to append the data by every click, see the @Gaby aka G. Petrioli's answer.

Comment: since he is using a counter as a parameter in the request, i assume that he wants to make multiple requests but not lose the previous values..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into other jQuery ajax methods besides `.load()` -- `.load()` will fill the selected element (the element with an ID of "loadbox" in this case) with the response returned by a request to the provided URL, and it will always overwrite the existing contents.

It sounds like what you want to do is *append* the response to the element. In that case, you could do:

```
$.ajax('mysqlquery.php?id=' + nameid, {
  dataType : 'html',
  success : function(html) {
    $('#loadbox').append(html);
  }
});
```